# How to adds 3 more days to the due date from the current date excluding the Holidays and weekend

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have a wf running that when a task is rejected, it adds 3 more days to the due date from the current date excluding the weekend. Now I want to exclude any federal holidays. If the due date (today+3 days) falls on a holiday or contains a holiday within the 3 day period, I want it to give the due date one more additional day (today+3 days + 1 day for the holiday). I created a list and did a look up to that list in the wf within a loop. The loop is set up to check all business days and compare it to the list but is failing-

Here is My Workflow that I Used:

```
If var:duedate starts with Wed

or var:duedate starts with Thurs

or var:duedate starts with Fri

 add 5 days to currentitem:duedate (output to var:newdate)
else if var:dueDate starts with Sat

 add 4 days to currentitem:duedate (output to var:newdate)
else

 add 3 days to currentitem:duedate (output to var:newdate)
set currentItem:duedate to var:newdate
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/234805/how-to-adds-3-more-days-to-the-due-date-from-the-current-date-excluding-the-week?noredirect=1#comment251228_234805

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
public enum XDateTimeType { Calendar = 0, Business = 1 };   

public class XDateTime
{
    #region Private Class Member Variable

    private DateTime _date;
    private XDateTimeType _type;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public XDateTime()
    {
        init(DateTime.Now, XDateTimeType.Calendar);
    }

    public XDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        init(dateTime, XDateTimeType.Calendar);
    }


    public XDateTime(string dateTime)
    {
        init(Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime), XDateTimeType.Calendar);
    }

    public XDateTime(string dateTime, XDateTimeType dateType)
    {
        init(Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime), dateType);
        check();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the type of the Smart Date which is a value of XDateTimeType enumeration
    /// and could be Calendar or Business type. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// If you set the DateType to Business type the value of the inner DateTime variable might be
    /// changed to the value of the closest next business date.
    /// </remarks>
    public XDateTimeType DateType
    {
        get { return _type; }
        set
        {
            _type = value;
            check();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value of the inner System.DateTime variable of the Smart Date.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// If you set the Date and the DateType is a Business type the value of the inner DateTime variable
    /// might be changed to the value of the closest next business date.
    /// </remarks>
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set
        {
            _date = value;
            check();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the value of the inner DateTime variable is a public Holiday, otherwise false.
    /// </summary>
    //public bool IsHoliday
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        return _holidays.ContainsValue(_date.ToString(_format));
    //    }
    //}

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the value of the inner DateTime variable is a work day, otherwise false.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsWorkDay
    {
        get
        {
            return !(_date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || _date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds given hours to the value of the inner DateTime variable considering the DateType value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hours">Hours to add.</param>
    public void AddHours(short hours)
    {
        _date = _date.AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(hours));
        check();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds one business or calendar day depending on the DateType value to the value of the inner DateTime variable.
    /// </summary>
    public void AddDay()
    {
        _date = _date.AddDays(1.0);
        check();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds given CALENDAR amount of days to the value of the inner DateTime variable. Always considers
    /// a value of DateType property and change the inner date according to this value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="days">Calendar days to add.</param>
    public void AddDays(short days)
    {
        _date = _date.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(days));
        check();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds given BUSINESS amount of days to the value of the inner DateTime variable. Always considers
    /// a value of DateType property and change the inner date according to this value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="days">Business days to add.</param>
    public void AddBusinessDays(short days)
    {
        double sign = Convert.ToDouble(Math.Sign(days));
        int unsignedDays = Math.Sign(days) * days;
        for (int i = 0; i < unsignedDays; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                _date = _date.AddDays(sign);
            }
            while (!this.IsWorkDay);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a new instance of the System.DateTime object with the value of Next Business Day counting from
    /// the value of the XDateTime object.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime NextBusinessDay()
    {
        DateTime date = _date;
        do
        {
            date = date.AddDays(1.0);
        }
        while (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
        return date;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a new instance of the System.DateTime object with the value of Previous Business Day counting from
    /// the value of the XDateTime object.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime PreviousBusinessDay()
    {
        DateTime date = _date;
        do
        {
            date = date.AddDays(-1.0);
        }
        while (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
        return date;
    }

    public int NumberOfBusinessDaysFrom(DateTime date)
    {
        double dayToAdd = -1;
        int numberOfBusinessDays = 0;

        if (date < _date)
        {
            dayToAdd = 1;
        }
        while (_date != date)
        {
            date = date.AddDays(dayToAdd);
            if (!(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
            {
                // if date is a working (business) day - increase a counter
                numberOfBusinessDays++;
            }
        }
        return numberOfBusinessDays;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes private members of the XDateTime object. For using in the class constructors only.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dateTime">Initial date.</param>
    /// <param name="dateType">Date type.</param>
    private void init(DateTime dateTime, XDateTimeType dateType)
    {
        _date = dateTime;
        _type = dateType;
        //initHolidays();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tests a value of the inner DateTime variable and changes it if needed.
    /// </summary>
    private void check()
    {
        if (_type == XDateTimeType.Business && !this.IsWorkDay)
        {
            _date = this.NextBusinessDay();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Usage:

```
XDateTime sDate = new XDateTime();
sDate.AddBusinessDays(3);
```